in ionic v7 and Angular 17, how to toggle between light and dark theme at runtime (dynamically)
I noticed when the phone theme is dark mode the app will be in dark mode by default and vice versa for light mode but I could not understand what's happening behind the scenes and how to switch the theme at runtime.
I have not try anything because I could not understand what is happening behind the scenes so I can implement an approach for this case, thank you.

Check documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode

By default, it'll use the system setting on the phone.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/theming/dark-mode
You can toggle it in code using .ion-palette-dark on the html element

go to variables.scss file and copy the css of the dark theme and paste in a class, I choose 'dark-theme', then I have defined this Service to handle the the toggle


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;
  private darkThemeClass = 'dark-theme';

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }

  setInitialTheme() {
    const savedThemePreference = localStorage.getItem('isDarkMode');
    const prefersDark = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches;

    if (savedThemePreference !== null) {
      this.toggleTheme(savedThemePreference === 'true');
    } else {
      this.toggleTheme(prefersDark);
    }
  }

  toggleTheme(isDarkMode: boolean) {
    if (isDarkMode) {
      this.renderer.addClass(document.body, this.darkThemeClass);
    } else {
      this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, this.darkThemeClass);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('isDarkMode', isDarkMode.toString());
  }
}



